# Reading class data into R

Tags: c++, r, file, data-visualization

I have a `C++` program that creates (lots of) data that I would like to analyze and visualize in `R`. Each data point has the folloing format:

```
struct DataPoint {
  int iteration;  // 1...100
  int n; // starting size that may decline throughout the iterations
  std::vector<double> data1 // this vector has the size (n)
  std::vector<double> data1 // this vector has the size n*(n-1)/2 
};
```

Each run consists of 100 iterations, so each run creates 100 of these data points. And of course I would like to repeat each experiment several times (at least 10, better 100 times) to have an adequate sample size.

The main objective is to compare 4 different settings, so each of these experiments runs 4 times. And last but not least, the really interesting thing is (hopefully) how these settings have different effects depending on varying starting sizes `n`, e.g. 25, 50, 100, 250, 1000.

So...I have all this data in C++ and would like to analyze and visualize it in R, but I wonder what format the ouput file should have so that I can then extract exactly what I need (e.g. all data with `iteration=1` or `n=25` or `setting=random`) in `R`. As you can see that is a lot of data, so should I split this in several files? Or should I have one huge vector that gets read all at once?

Should have have one line for each data point? Should that be pre-formatted (e.g. `it1 <- c(0.1, 2.1, ...) or a simple` CSV` file?

**TLDR:** What format should the file(s) have to import data with varying vector lengths into R?

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I would probably write an Rcpp function to export the struct directly into R as a list. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Your question does not contain any mention of binary formats. Would something like HDF5 work for your situation?

Comment: @Botje I have not mentioned binary formats because I didn't even think of this as a possibility. And while writing the data in pure binary shouldn't be a problem, I'm afraid that I've never heard of HDF5 before and from what I just read, using it is a bit outside of my capabilities. :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use your C++ code to output to R directly. The Rcpp package is very helpful here. Suppose we write a function that creates objects of type DataPoint:

```
#include<vector>

struct DataPoint {
  int iteration;
  int n;
  std::vector<double> data1 ;
  std::vector<double> data2 ;
};

DataPoint my_function(int iteration, int n) {
  std::vector<double> data1;
  std::vector<double> data2;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    data1.push_back(static_cast<float>(i)/10);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < (n * (n - 1))/2; ++i) {
    data2.push_back(static_cast<float>(i)/20);
  }
  DataPoint result = {iteration, n, data1, data2};
  return result;
}
```

To export the output of a DataPoint object directly to R, we can add this to the bottom of our file.

```cpp
#include<Rcpp.h>

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List data_point(int iteration, int n) {

  DataPoint dp = my_function(iteration, n);
  Rcpp::List res = Rcpp::List::create(Rcpp::Named("iteration") = dp.iteration,
                                      Rcpp::Named("n") = dp.n,
                                      Rcpp::Named("data1") = dp.data1,
                                      Rcpp::Named("data2") = dp.data2);
  return res;
}
```

When the file is sourced in RStudio, we will have an R function available called `data_point` that invokes the C++ code and returns the struct as an R list. For example:

```r
data_point(1, 5)
$iteration
[1] 1

$n
[1] 5

$data1
[1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4

$data2
 [1] 0.00 0.05 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That does indeed sound great and I deduce that you recommend using a `list` object in R! The only thing that is not clear to me is how I get that `RTCPP::List` object into `R` or better yet, the 100*10*4 (iterations*repeats*settings) Datapoints. Should that be a nested list?

Comment: @Markstar if you are working with RStudio and you have a single C++ implementation file, you can simply add my code at the end of your file and press the `source` button to compile it. The `data_point` function will then be available to you in R. If you have multiple implementation files, then it is best to create a package and use the `build` option. A nested list would be sensible as the output. You can write another C++ function that iterates over `data_point` and outputs a list of its results.

Comment: The C++ code is a Visual Studio project with about 20 files, so what you are saying is that I would have to learn how to make a Rccp package first to then integrate that package into RStudio? Hmm. To be honest, I was hoping for something simpler for a newbie like me. But thank you again for your time, I think your approach is very elegant and if I was a more skillful programmer, that's would be perfect.